# How to uniquely identify a face with computer vision

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am using the face_recognition python package to process images of people and detect the landmarks on their faces.

I actually want to create an ID for each user based on his/her face characteristics.

How can I uniquely identify a face using the landmarks? What makes 2 faces different or the same?

Is it the distance between their eyes, nose, lips, something about the chin? What is it unique in each one of us?

Comment: this is way too broad. you need to read up on this topic before you can ask a useful question. there's no point in asking if you haven't even researched the issue. please review [ask].

Comment: Biometrics is very difficult, we are still trying to figure out how to detect those characteristics. Search for "Survey + Face Recognition" on google academics or arxiv. If you want to start, you can try to use a method called LBP or SURF, search for LBP face recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeepFace wraps many facial recognition models such as FaceNet, VGG or ArcFace. These models basically represent faces as vectors. Then, vectors for same person should be more similar than the vectors for different persons. Here, the library uses euclidean and cosine to find the similarity between vectors. If the distance between those two vectors is less than a pre-tuned threshold value, then this pair is classified as same person. [Here](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/commons/distance.py#L28), you can find the pre-tuned threshold values for models and metric pairs.

If you want to find the vector embedding of a face, then you can use represent function of deepface. For instance, Facenet model generates 128 dimensional vectors.

```
from deepface import DeepFace
vector_embedding = DeepFace.represent("img.jpg", model_name = "Facenet")
assert isinstance(vector_embedding, list)
assert len(vector_embedding) == 128
```

Comment: That's a great answer. Tested it and it works pretty good. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this python package which can detect, verify, .. faces

https://github.com/serengil/deepface

Comment: Great but how it helps to generate unique identifiers for the faces?